# Using canvg.js how to write svg to canvas along with style for d3 visualization?

Tags: javascript

I have to `load Image urls` for `pdf reporting`. SO I need to convert `charts` like `scatter plot` , `volcano plot` etc into `dataURL(JPEG)` type. For this Iam using `canvg.js` , but it gives a `black rectangle` as it `does not consider` any of the `d3 styles`. Is there any other way to resolve this?
Below is the code snippet. Also wanted to know if there is a better way to convert svg elements into canvas along with style elements.

```
  function getImgData(chartContainer,backgroundColor) {
        var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
            var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
                         var chartDoc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
              canvas = chartDoc.createElement('canvas'); 
                    canvas.setAttribute('width',  chartArea.offsetWidth);
            canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);
                    canvas.setAttribute(
                'style',
                'position: absolute;' +
                'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
                'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');

            chartDoc.body.appendChild(canvas);
             canvg(canvas, svg,{ renderCallback: function () {
                                 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                 var w = canvas.width;
                var h = canvas.height;

                 if(backgroundColor)
                        {
                            context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
                            context.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
                            context.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

                        } 
                 var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/JPEG");
                                  window.open(imgURL);
                             }});$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#pdfBtn').click(function () { 


            var chartContainer = document.getElementById('vis');
            var chartDoc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
            doc.text("hi world!");      
            getImgData(chartContainer,'white');

    });
```

Comment: Please share your relevant codes for this.

Comment: I'm struggling with something similar, did you have any solution for this  issue?